# Computing Malliavin Derivative for European Call Payoff

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, greeks, delta-hedging, malliavin-calculus

Let $X_t$ be a continuous local-martingale modeling the stock price given by
$$
X_t = \int_0^t \sigma_t(T,K)dW_t
,
$$ 
and $\sigma_t(T,K)$ is an $L^2$-measurable process not adapted to $W_t$'s filtration (like a stochastic volatility process).

I want to compute some Greeks, in particular I'm looking at $K$ be a strike price and $T$ be a future time of maturity.  I'm interested in computing the quantity
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[
D_t(X_t - K)_+
\right]
,
$$
where $D_t$ is the Malliavin Derivative operator.